# Spring framework

Tags: java, spring

In what case is it important to use Spring framework? 
Please make clear about what are advantages and also more about it. I am new to Spring framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Why Use Spring](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/Section/Why-Use-the-Spring-Framework-.id-130098.html). this may help you. [One linked Stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4017014/why-use-spring)